# How to translate a rectangle to the previous mouse coordinates in processing

Tags: java, oop, processing, pacman

I'm brand new to java and I'm making a snake game. My next step is to add a rectangle to the snake whenever it eats food. My current thinking is, I want to add an identical rectangle that's translated to the previous position of (mouseX, mouseY). At least, translated a distance of one rectangle from the previous one, but oriented where the mouse previously was, to "follow" behind the piece in front of it. I'm not sure how to go about doing that, but here is my code thus far.

```py
//snake
void snake() {
    rect(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
}

class Snake {

    //variables
    int len;
    int wid;
    int xcord;
    int ycord;

    //constructor
    Snake(int x,int y, int len, int wid) {
        this.len = len;
        this.wid = wid;
        this.xcord = x;
        this.ycord = y;
        rect(xcord, ycord, wid, len);
    }

    //clear screen
    void  update() {
        background(255);
        rectMode(CENTER);
        rect(mouseX, mouseY, wid, len);
    }
}

class Food {

    //variables
    int xcord;
    int ycord;
    int wid;
    int len;

    //constructor
    Food() {
        this.xcord = int(random(width - 5));
        this.ycord = int(random(height - 5));
        this.wid = 10;
        this.len = 10;
        rect(xcord, ycord, wid, len);
    }

    //update food position
    void update() {
        if( (mouseX > xcord) && (mouseX < xcord + wid) &&
            (mouseY > ycord) && (mouseY < ycord + len)) {
            xcord = int(random(width - 5));
            ycord = int(random(height - 5));
            //lengthen snake
        }
    }

    //display food
    void displayFood() {
        rect(xcord, ycord, 10, 10);
    }
}

Snake s;
Food f;
void setup() {
    background(255);
    s = new Snake(mouseX, mouseY, 10, 10);
    f = new Food();
}

void draw() {
    s.update();

    f.update();
    f.displayFood();
}
```

Comment: How do you want it to follow, just "go in the direction of that other cube you're linked to" or more like "follow the exact same path than the other cube you're following" ??

Answer (score 1):

You make 2 variables

```
float pMouseX = mouseX;
float pMouseY = mouseY;
```

Then, in draw, **after** updating the snake, you update those variables:

```
s.update
pMouseX = mouseX;
pMouseX = mouseY;
```

For having more than 2 rectangles, instead of single variables, consider using an [ArrayList](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) of [arrays](https://processing.org/reference/Array.html).

An Array is basically a way to store multiple variables in one variable.
An ArrayList is similar, but it doesn't have a set size. This means that you can keep adding elements to ArrayLists, which is something you can't do with Arrays.

You can declare such an ArrayList like this:

```
ArrayList<float[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<float[]>(); //each element of the ArrayList is an array, which contains an x and y position
```

To get the x and y coordinates of any rectangle, use `arrayList.get(indexOfTheRectangle)[0] //use 1 instead of 0 for the y coordinate`
 and update them like this:

```
for (int i = arrayList.length - i; i > 0; i++) { //you need to go through the array backwards, because otherwise, for each element, you end up changing the value it is supposed to get, which results in all elements having the same value.
   arrayList[i] = arrayList[i - 1]; 
}
arrayList[0] = new float[]{mouseX, mouseY}
```